# Jquery .position is null convert to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, null, offset

I have searched online and cannot find the answer to this issue yet..

I have a jquery `.position` statement that changes the css of an element, but fails if the position returns null. How can I convert the null value to 0 in order to add to the position?

```
    var menu = $('.menu');
    var menuposition = menu.offset();
        $('.other').css('top', menuposition.top + 100);
```

If the value of menuposition is `null` the statement fails.. Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

What about setting a default for the menu position? like so...

```
var menu = $('.menu');
var menuposition = menu.offset() || {top:0};
    $('.other').css('top', menuposition.top + 100);
```

Comment: I think you mean `|| {top:0}` as your code as is will throw an error as 0 (number object) has no `top` property

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the downsides of having API's that returns `null`. The [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern could have been used here to simplify the API, relieving the clients from dealing with null values.

".offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left"

Therfore, you can do something like:

```
var menuOffset = menu.offset() || { top: 0, left: 0 },
    menuTop = menuOffset.top + 100;

$('.other').css('top', menuTop + 'px');
```

Comment: @Nit It's more efficient since your save one property lookup, one function call and any processing that function might be doing (which could be expensive, but I haven't looked at the implementation).

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @plalx It can still use one call with one var -- `var menuposition = menu.offset() || { top: 0, left: 0 };`

Comment: Ok thanks but the only potential problem is that the menu moves based on scroll location (i.e. responsive navbar, at the beginning is 20 px down and as scrolling goes to the top). I'm saying that if it is at the top I cannot access the value..

Comment: @NickB You can substract `$(window).scrollTop()` from `menuTop`.

Comment: @Nit Well, if it doesn't add complexity to the code and make it less readable, I think it's just efficient code, not premature optimization. It's like caching the `length` property of an array before iterating to save on property lookups. It doesn't harm readability and is much more efficient. However, in this case it wasn't necessary since it could have be written in a single statement. It was quite obvious, not sure what I was thinking ;)

Comment: @plalx can you help me determine what this would look like in your code? I really appreciate your help!